# Can I change the NAT type when using my phone as a tether for Gaming?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, tethering, wifi-tethering

I want to play online with my Switch while I'm on the go, but it seems my NAT type is D, which is too low to enable online play.

So is there a way to change that NAT type while tethering to my Android phone? Can I change the NAT type from my phone, or do something in my Switch parameters to force another NAT type?

PS: If the solution could not involve rooting my phone I'd prefer it.

Comment: Yeah I dont see myself setting up a laptop, phone and switch in the bus. Is there a way to emulate that?

Comment: Mmmm not that I can think of....Wait you can try using an alternative tethering app like Foxfi, Open garden, Barnacle wifi tether.

Comment: Ok, I'll try them out.